# Tell git that modified line is not new line

Tags: git, version-control

I modified a parameter on a function and now git recognizes it as an entirely new line of code. The first line of code below represents the original code, and the second line represents the "new" line after I changed one parameter. The first line was originally on line 1 and the new line is now on line 10 (because I didn't make an atomic commit, and I believe this is the main problem).

```
// on line 1 originally
const myFunction = (someArray: Array<{ id: string; name: string; }>, index: number) => {

// now on line 10
const myFunction = (someArray: Array<{ id: string; name: string; }>, index: string) => {
```

Is there any way to tell git that line 10 is just line 1 modified so that it doesn't seem like so much churn is happening?

Comment: You say "because I didn't make an atomic commit"; does that mean you want to split that commit into 2 different commits?

Comment: What I meant was I should have added and committed the change in parameter separately from adding and committing additional code that pushed the function down a few lines. I was wondering if this would have prevented git from treating the function as entirely new code.

Comment: If you think that's what you should have done, what is preventing you from rebasing and doing that?  It sounds like you do indeed want to split your commit into 2 commits. `git` gives you the power to do that.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't really make sense. Git tracks the entire contents of the file with every commit. The only time things can be called "added", "modified", or "deleted" is when your *diffing* two things. In the case of a line that has been moved, this will always be treated as a deletion and an insertion by diffing tools.

Comment: Though, note that some diff tools (various Git add-ons, and the diffs shown by many web hosting sites) will highlight the changed words within the changed lines. You can also run `git diff --word-diff`.

Comment: What made me curious was how when I rename a file, Git will either count it as a deletion/creation of a new file, or I can tell Git to track the renamed file as the old file, so I wondered if I could do the same thing within an individual file.